# Mode 7 in xna/monogame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, matrix

I want achieve a view like Mode 7 from snes games where the closer textures get stretched out more and more far away textures look smaller. Something like this:

[image: Mode 7]

What I have in my project at the moment is a flat 2d floor made from multiple textures aligned next to each other, but I'm not sure on how to add perspective to it. I'm using a matrix to transform the view, but when I tried using Matrix.CreatePerspective I only got an empty view. Is this effect possible to achieve using matrices? Or do I have to use the billboard effect on every texture that I'm drawing? And if so, how do I make it so that it's still possible to rotate the camera in every direction? I'm new to matrices and 3d in Monogame, so this is still confusing to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a flat plane in 3D for this, set texture sampling to point sampling and use Matrix.CreateLookAt for the view matrix.

I suggest you read up on what the world, view and projection matrices are and what they do.